# Absolute css positioning shows white space on android html

Tags: android, html, css

When displaying the result of this HTML code on my galaxy tab 2, with "html viewer", there is a small empty white space between the header and content div, in portrait mode.

http://jsfiddle.net/jkvuwn2h/

(On this fiddle the space will not appear ;)

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="content">content</div>
<div id="navigation">nav</div>
<div id="header">header</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{width:100%;padding:0;background:#fff;margin:0;height:100%;}
#header, #content, #footer, #navigation{margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;display:block;float:left;clear:both;width:100%;}
#header{background:green;display:block;height:33%;padding-bottom:0px;margin-bottom:0px;}
#navigation{background:blue;display:block;height:5%;}
#content{position:absolute;top:38%;background:red;display:block;height:57%;padding-top:0px;margin-top:0px;}    
#footer{background:teal;display:block;height:5%;}
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Android is not very good at adding up percentages some times. It seems it can get confused by rounding numbers.

You could account for this my offsetting the position slightly so it appears beneath the `#header` and there is a tiny overlap:

```
#header {
    background:green;
    display:block;
    height:33%;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    z-index: 2; /* make it appear above #content */
}

#content{
    position:absolute;
    top:37%; /* reduced by 1% to allow for rounding issue */
    background:red;
    display:block;
    height: 58%; /* increased by 1% to account for reduced top value */
    padding-top:0px;
    margin-top: 0;
    z-index: 1; /* appear behind #header */
}
```